# How to write in super large letters in an ordinary textfield?

Tags: youtube, text, font

I came across a YouTube whose title was made of letters that were not part of its logo. Here is the link: <strike>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZkgIjJlsxA</strike> (**it appears they letters have been removed, or YouTube disabled it**). These letters are considered part of the text and provide a huge advantage over other videos in terms of visibility.

How did the makers of this video create these giant letters?

Is it a special font, or perhaps a hack using some foreign writing system?

Comment: The title directly below the video?  Looks the same as any other video to me.

Comment: I can't see any difference either.  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @LoganGoesPlaces & techturtle I'm am sorry, I attached the wrong link. It's fixed now. Please see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done using [block element characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements) that look like they spell another word:

█▬█ █ ▀█▀

It is actually an ASCII art with the following characters: █ ▬ ▀

It can't be used to spell all letters of the alphabet, but you can try. Other characters can help as well.

Here I just wrote the first part of your username: █ ╔╦╗
I gave up because the R is hard to draw, but I am sure there are some online generators out there.

I am not sure YouTube approves of using such tricks, though.

Comment: Thanks, but how is "┗ ╔╦╗ " the first part of my username?

Comment: Haha sorry I misread your username as "LMRAY" fixed.

Comment: lol no problem. How would you make a bold thick "M" rather than the "M" you used?

Comment: It might not be possible to achieve exactly the shapes you want. Copy-paste characters from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements and arrange them like you wish :-)

Comment: Great thanks! Can you upvote me so I can upvote your answer (I need 15 points! :)

Answer (score 4):

Enter any text [in this web site](https://fsymbols.com/generators/) and get it translated as big block characters in different styles.

```
╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭╮
╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱┃┃
╭━━┳━━┳━━┫┃
┃╭━┫╭╮┃╭╮┃┃
┃╰━┫╰╯┃╰╯┃╰╮
╰━━┻━━┻━━┻━╯
```

**Just need to click on the tabs on top for selecting style: Flip, Bold, Blocky, Bubble, etc.**

For example:

- [TArty - Generate big artful text signs](https://fsymbols.com/generators/tarty/)
- [Carty - Generate BIG text art signs](https://fsymbols.com/generators/carty/)
- [Blocky texts](https://fsymbols.com/generators/blocky/)